# How Can I Make This Approximation?

Tags: approximation

I've been tasked with showing that

$\frac{\delta m}{m_0}$~$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{v}{c}))^2$

From $\frac{m}{m_0}$$=$$1$$-$$(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{v}{c}))^2$

Assuming v is small.

Im not sure what approximation I am supposed to make to show this. And that is all I am given. My intuition says some approximation where v is much much small than c allows me to do this but I am not sure where to go from there.

Any nudge in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: Write down what is $\delta m=m_0-m$, as a function of $v$. Then write $\frac{\delta m}{m_0}$. Finally, if you assume that $v/c$ is small compared to $1$, then $1-v^2/c^2\approx 1$

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrei!